# How to get string length at compile time if possible?

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, string-literals, compile-time

Consider a BasicCharp class with two constructors:

```cpp
template <class CharType>
class BasicCharp {
    public:
        using value_type    = CharType;
        using pointer       = value_type*;
        public:
//1
            template<size_t SIZE>
            constexpr BasicCharp(value_type (&str)[SIZE]) noexcept
                : m_Length(SIZE)
                , m_String(str) {}
//2
            constexpr BasicCharp(pointer string) noexcept
                : m_Length(countElems(string))
                , m_String(string) {}
        private:
        size_t m_Length;
        pointer m_String;
};
```

Constructing:

```cpp
BasicCharp<const char> str = "test";
```

This calls constructor 2, however if there is no constructor 2, this does call constructor 1.

How to keep constructor 2, but enforce using constructor 1 if possible?

A c++17 solution is preferred, but any standart is welcome.

The goal is to deduce string literal's size at compile time, but if a pointer is passed, size should be calculated by the constructor.

Comment: If you compute the length only at "runtime", did you check that the calculation is not optimized away?

Comment: What is `value_type`? What is `m_length`? What is `m_String`? What is `pointer`? What is `countElems`?

Comment: No, not yet tested if the calculation is optimized away. Trying to figure that out right now.
@SamVarshavchik edited for more clarification. countElems basically does the same as strlen in this example.

Comment: It seems to optimize the size calculation with -O2 flag, if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but you might tag dispatch, something like:

```
template <typename > struct Tag{};


template <class CharType>
class BasicCharp {
// ...
public:
    template<typename T>
    constexpr BasicCharp(const T& str) noexcept : BasicCharp(str, Tag<T>{})
    {
        // Or alternatively, use if constexpr here
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t SIZE>
    constexpr BasicCharp(const value_type (&str)[SIZE],
                         Tag<value_type[SIZE]>) noexcept
        : m_Length(SIZE)
        , m_String(str) {}

    constexpr BasicCharp(const value_type*string, Tag<const value_type*>) noexcept
        : m_Length(countElems(string))
        , m_String(string) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your overloads are ambiguous; a decayed array pointer is no better or worse candidate than a non-decayed one. It only compiles because non-template overloads are a better match than template ones.

What you can do is make the pointer overload a worse overload candidate, e.g. by introducing a user-defined conversion sequence.

```
        struct ptr { pointer p; ptr(pointer p) : p(p) {} };

        constexpr BasicCharp(ptr string) noexcept
            : m_Length(countElems(string.p))
            , m_String(string.p) {}
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but for some reason my compiler treats this overload as not valid for a `const char *` argument. I need to explicitly cast it to the `struct ptr` type for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the result to constexpr variable, but it is not 100% garanted that this will be done compile time, also you can use consteval, in this case if variable isn't assigned compile time you will get error(consteval works from c++20)